# Timeline loop don't start after event

Tags: javafx

i am learing more about javaFx and especially of Timeline, but i go already a problem.
After i press the "start" button, the timeline loop dont start. 
I dont get any error, so i dont know why the timeline loop never start.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 */
public class StartServer extends Application {

    Stage window;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        TextField txtPort = new TextField();
        Label lblPort = new Label("Number");
        Button startServer = new Button("Start");

        startServer.setOnAction(e-> startServer(Integer.parseInt(txtPort.getText())));

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.add(lblPort,0,0);
        gridPane.add(txtPort,1,0);
        gridPane.add(startServer,0,1,2,1);
        gridPane.setHgap(10);
        gridPane.setVgap(10);
      // startServer(8888);

        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 200,100);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }

    private void startServer(int port){
        System.out.println("Timelineloop");

            Timeline time = new Timeline( new KeyFrame(      Duration.millis(2500),k->{
                System.out.println("Timelineloop");

            }));
            time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            time.play();
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately after you call `play()` on your timeline you are calling `close()` on your stage.  Closing the last stage in a JavaFX application will shut down the JavaFX system and, if there are no other non-daemon threads in the system (as in this case), will shut down the JVM, exiting your program.

You can modify this behavior either by not closing the last stage in your JavaFX application or by calling [`Platform.setImplicitExit(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-) before you close the last stage and later calling [`Platform.exit()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#exit--) when JavaFX is no longer needed.

The application life-cycle behavior is further described in the [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html) javadoc.

One note on your example: to get the Timeline to run, comment out `window.close()` and ensure you enter an integer value in the text field before pressing the start button (or your `Integer.parseInt` call will throw an exception).